# Expanding an EditText to the left

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an EditText, which expands to the right when I enter text (standard behaviour of an EditText).
Is it possible to create an EditText that expands to the left when I enter text?

Comment: Set gravity left for it.

Comment: For the EditText itself, or the containing layout? Setting the EditText-Layout to Left doesn't do anything, if I set it to RIGHT, the texts starts on the right and "flows" to the left, but the EditText still expands to the right.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your problem :

```
EditText t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

set the `t.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); or LEFT`, that makes entered text left or right alignement.

**Update**  look [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html)

Comment: I tried that, but the EditText still expands to the left, although the  text begins on the right.